# Update Textbox on after PHP GET

Tags: php

I'm a complete beginner with web development and I'm facing a problem. I have a navigation bar, with a search form that 'gets' to search.php
Sample URL : `http:/....search.php?s=asdas`
I would want to get the value of `$_GET['s']` and place it in a textbox with the `id = 'filter-searchbox'`
My code so far goes like this :

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['s'])){
    $searchWord = $_GET['s'];
    ?>
    <script>
document.getElementById('filter-searchbar').value =<?php $searchWord ?> ;
    </script>
<?php   }

?>

<h3> <div class="label label-default"> Search for Events </div></h3>
<BR>

<div id="filter" class="col-md-3">

<input id='filter-searchbar' name='searchWord' type="text" class="form-control"    placeholder="Search Events..." value= "" ><br>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Rewritten the code, Try this,

```
<?php 
    $searchWord="";
    if(isset($_GET['s'])){
        $searchWord = $_GET['s'];
    }
 ?>

 <input id='filter-searchbar' name='searchWord' type="text" class="form-control"    placeholder="Search Events..." 
    value= "<?php echo $searchWord;?>" ><br>
```

Comment: `echo htmlspecialchars($searchWord);`

Answer (score 0):

You missed `echo` and  should write this `echo "'".$searchWord ."'";` below the `input` tag.

Because the `document.getElementById('filter-searchbar')...` statement would executed successfully after only the dom is ready.

```
<h3> <div class="label label-default"> Search for Events </div></h3>
<BR>

<div id="filter" class="col-md-3">

<input id='filter-searchbar' name='searchWord' type="text" class="form-control" /> 


<?php 
if(isset($_GET['s'])){
    $searchWord = $_GET['s'];
    ?>
    <script>
    document.getElementById('filter-searchbar').value = <?php echo "'".$searchWord ."'"; ?> ;

    </script>
<?php   }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('filter-searchbar').value = is missing an echo statement.